# REST API PATCH request

Tags: c#, rest, mailchimp

I'm trying to send requests and get responses from MailChimp API . . so far, GET, POST and DELETE are working good however, PATCH always results to Bad Request can you identify the error in this code?

```
string data = "{\"name\": \"TestListTWOTWOTWO\"}";
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(uri);
request.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Authorization] = accessToken;
request.Method = "PATCH";
request.ContentType = "text/plain;charset=utf-8";

System.Text.UTF8Encoding encoding = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();
byte[] bytes = encoding.GetBytes(data);
request.ContentLength = bytes.Length;

    using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
    {
        // Send the data.
        requestStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    }
    var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    var responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
```

the error occus on the line with request.GetResponse();
it is an unhandled WebException saying The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request

after checking the error response, here's the what it says

```
"Your request doesn't appear to be valid JSON:

\nParse error on line 1:\nPATCH /3.0/lists/9bb\n^\n
Expected one of: 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '['"
```

Comment: It's good idea to enclose the error message.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Many C# libraries seem to try to use the `Expect: 100-Continue` header, which MailChimp/Akamai has a problem with when combined with PATCH. You have two options.

1. Turn off Expect: 100-Continue in your HTTP library. In one C# library, you do that with a line of code like `Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.ExpectContinue = False`
2. Tunnel the PATCH request through HTTP POST using the `X-Http-Method-Override` header. [Here's more details on that header](https://developers.google.com/gdata/docs/2.0/basics?csw=1#UpdatingEntry).

Comment: option 2 saved my life. Thanks a bunch, now I'm nowhere near to pulling my hair again

Comment: Option 2 saved me too! Thank you! I implemented this with: request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Post 
and
request.Headers.Add("X-Http-Method-Override", "PATCH")

Comment: I also had this trouble using .net system.net.webclient object, and I solved it that way:
1. in the code: ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = False 
OR 2. in the web.config: 
<system.net><settings><servicePointManager expect100Continue="false" /></settings></system.net>

Answer (score 0):

Cause `PATCH` is a quite new RFC, so you would not expect that more then a few services support it at all. You'd better check that if the service supports it.

You send request using json format, but set content type to "text/plain" is that OK?

Comment: so far, I encountered no problems with POST and GET methods using text/plain as Content type